# Why is appending to a file faster then writing to it?

Tags: node.js, append, filesystems

I am experimenting with different write opartions and have noticed that appending to existing file is 2x as fast as writing the same string to tthe file. This simple script runs 1000 iterations of `appendFileSync` or `writeFileSync`. `writeFileSync` takes 150ms while `appendFileSync` takes only 70ms.

What makes appending faster than writing?

```
   function writeTest(){
        let start = new Date().getTime();
        for (let index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
            fs.writeFileSync('db', 'muc,10'); // or fs.appendFileSync("db","muc,10")
        }
        let end = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(end-start);

    }
    writeTest();
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call writeFileSync it creates a new file if one does not exist, If one does exist, than it replaces it. Replacing a file will take longer than just adding data to an existing file.